# Unable to load jquery using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Just for fun, I want to load `jquery` using `require.js`. So, I made the following:

**amd.js**

```
define(["jquery-3.3.1"], function($) {
    console.log(typeof $);              // reports undefined
    $("h1").html("Hello from AMD");     // causes TypeError (see below)
});
```

My HTML file is really simple and just has a blank `<h1`> element and the usual `require.js` definition.

```
<script data-main = "amd" src = "require.js"></script>
```

Also, my root folder, where everything is, also contains the `jquery-3.3.1.js` source file.

You may see the whole example code [here on my github repo](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/tree/master/JavaScript/loader-question). Ignore all files except:

1. amd.html
2. amd.js
3. jquery-3.3.1.js
4. require.js

However, when I access the page, whether using the `file:///` protocol or using a web server, the module is not loaded and I see a blank page.

The console reports `undefined` for the `console.log` statement, and reports the following exception for the second statement where I access the `jQuery` object/function, and it is what gets returned from the module.

> TypeError: $ is not a function

I am using jquery version 3.3.1. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L33) of this (and any) version of jquery, it is well known that jquery is a function object. See below:

**From the jQuery source**

```
define( [
    ...
], function( ..., ..., ... ) {

    jQuery = function( selector, context ) {

        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },

    return jQuery;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enter 'jquery' into your requirejs config?

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib', // path to your source
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-3.3.1' // invoke
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: No. I thought a config was optional and only required if you wanted to specify paths where paths were not on your local file system. For e.g. when you wanted to import a module from a CDN. Is this absolutely required. You mean require.js won't work without a config?

Comment: no your right, its only recommend to use the way it is intended. But certainly doesn't matter your correct!

Comment: also note according to requre.js webpage documentation it says - 
    // THIS WILL NOT WORK
    `define(['lib/jquery'], function ($) {...});`